vs code extention configuration
First of all, I'm still learning about Java
now i want to try using spring-boot in vscode
but after I installed the extension for springboot , the following error appeared when I opened the pom.xml file
Command failed: mvn -q help:effective-pom -Doutput="\c:\Users\ISan BigBro\Documents\Tugas-tugas\zip\prak oop\Tugas Akhir\demoapp\effective-pom.xml" -f "/c:/Users/ISan BigBro/Documents/Tugas-tugas/zip/prak oop/Tugas Akhir/demoapp/pom.xml" POM file "/c:/Users/ISan BigBro/Documents/Tugas-tugas/zip/prak oop/Tugas Akhir/demoapp/pom.xml" specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist

It seems that the error arises from the Red Hat dependency analysis extension
What should i do to fix it?
on the other hand I understand that this error appears related to the PATH I use
I have ensured that the PATH of the pom.xml and the PATH of the maven extension for Java are correct
I did some things I searched on the internet, one of which was to create an effective pom.xml with the code used in cmd
C:\apache-maven-3.9.7\bin\mvn.cmd help:effective-pom -Doutput="C:\Users\ISan BigBro\Documents\Tasks\zip\prak oop\Final Tasks\demoapp\effective -pom .xml" -f "C:\Users\ISan BigBro\Documents\Assignments\zip\prac oop\Final Assignment\demoapp\pom.xml"

